# WritableBitmap high speed drawing on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm experimenting with `WritableBitmapEx` on Windows Phone. I created a simple example, a simple box moving up and down.

There's a draw function which redraws the rectangle each frame:

```
    int y = 0;
    int dy = 15;
    public void draw()
    {
        y += dy;

        if (y > 500 || y < 0)
            dy = -dy;

        writeableBmp.Clear(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black);
        writeableBmp.FillRectangle(0, y, 100, y + 100, System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green);
    }
```

and the `Loaded` event which creates the Writable bitmap and also calls `draw()` on each frame.

```
    WriteableBitmap writeableBmp;
    private async void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        writeableBmp = BitmapFactory.New((int)ContentPanel.ActualWidth, (int)ContentPanel.ActualHeight);
        image.Source = writeableBmp;
        writeableBmp.GetBitmapContext();
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;
    }

    private void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        draw();
    }
```

But this is giving my ~30FPS at most, so the animation is not smooth.

I *know* that there are some better ways of creating such animations in `xaml` (creating a rectangle object and animating using xaml animations for example), but there's a game (in another language) that redraws each frame this way, and my ultimate goal is porting that code to Windows Phone. So finding a way to redraw fast enough makes porting **really** easier.

So, is there a way to improve performance of this? or is there a better way to draw each frame manually, but fast enough (60fps)?

Comment: What's the reason for downvote?

Comment: I remember several years back that WP was limited to about 30 FPS.  I think that restriction has been lifted, but I suspect with low end phones like the 520 still can't reach much higher than that.  Maybe this is still the case, but if you're porting a game, have you tried Win2D by Microsoft yet?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware Well, I'm testing on Lumia 930, still I'm getting ~30fps. Can you explain more about Win2D? How easy and how fast is drawing with that?

Comment: it basically just a wrapper over Direct2D, so probably as fast as you gonna get unless you go native.  You can get it using NuGet or their GitHub : https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D , getting started projects (imho it's very easy) : https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-samples

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware I'm playing with it, and it seems to be what I'm looking for. Can you post it in an answer so I can upvote it? :)

Comment: np, good luck, Looking forward to your game if you're releasing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out Microsoft Win2D.  You can get it using NuGet or their GitHub here: [Microsoft Win2D GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D).  It's basically a wrapper over Direct2D and very simple to use.

Features (Copied from : https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D/wiki/Features)

> **Easy-to-use Windows Runtime API**
>
> •Available from .NET and C++
>
> •Supports Windows 10, Windows 8.1, and Windows Phone 8.1
>
> **Immediate mode 2D graphics rendering with GPU acceleration**
>
> •Implemented as a layer on top of Direct2D, DirectImage, and DirectWrite
>
> •Interop to and from underlying types, so you can mix & match Win2D with native D2D
>
> **Bitmap graphics**
>
> •Load, save, and draw bitmap images
>
> •Render to texture
>
> •Use bitmaps as opacity masks
>
> •Sprite batch API for efficiently drawing large numbers of bitmaps
>
> •Use block compressed bitmap formats to save memory
>
> •Load, save, and draw virtual bitmaps, which can be larger than the maximum GPU texture size and are automatically split into tiles
>
> **Vector graphics**
>
> •Draw primitive shapes (lines, rectangles, circles, etc.) or arbitrarily complex geometry
>
> •Fill shapes using solid colors, image brushes, or linear and radial gradients
>
> •Draw lines of any width with flexible stroke styles (dotted, dashed, etc.)
>
> •High quality antialiasing
>
> •Rich geometry manipulation (union, intersect, compute point on path, tessellate, etc.)
>
> •Clip drawing to arbitrary geometric regions
>
> •Capture drawing operations in command lists for later replay
>
> •Rasterize ink strokes (from a stylus)
>
> Powerful image processing effects
>
> •Blurs
>
> •Blends
>
> •Color adjustments (brightness, contrast, exposure, highlights & shadows, etc.)
>
> •Filters (convolve, edge detection, emboss, sharpen)
>
> •Lighting
>
> •Custom pixel shaders
>
> •And many more...
>
> **Text**
>
> •Fully internationalized Unicode text rendering
>
> •Text layouts can be drawn, measured, or hit-tested against
>
> •Convert text outlines to geometry
>
> •Enumerate fonts and query their metrics
>
> •Draw or manipulate individual glyph runs to create custom text layouts
>
> **UI integration**
>
> •XAML CanvasControl make it easy to get up and running
>
> •Can also create advanced things like owner-draw XAML controls
>
> •XAML CanvasAnimatedControl provides Update/Draw game loop programming model
>
> •XAML CanvasVirtualControl for drawing to very large virtualized surfaces
>
> •Draw onto Windows.UI.Composition drawing surfaces and swapchains
>
> •Can also draw directly to a CoreWindow
>
> •Printing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Chubosaurus Software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188883/chubosaurus-software) who suggested Microsoft Win2D.

I'm gonna explain a little more about what I did in my case.

There's a control called `CanvasAnimatedControl` in Win2D, which is specially designed for this purpose.

After getting the package from NuGet and adding it to the page, you can use two events `Draw` and `Update`.

`Update` for the logic, and `Draw` is where you render the frame.

So, this is the code for the moving rectangle which described in the question:

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cvs.Update += Cvs_Update;
        cvs.Draw += Cvs_Draw;
    }

    int y = 0;
    int dy = 15;
    private void Cvs_Draw(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        args.DrawingSession.Clear(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue);
        args.DrawingSession.FillRectangle(new Rect(0, y, 100, 100), Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
    }

    private void Cvs_Update(Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml.CanvasAnimatedUpdateEventArgs args)
    {
        y += dy;

        if (y > 500 || y < 0)
            dy = -dy;
    }
```

This code runs great (~60fps) on my phone.

The only downside is, Win2D supports Windows Phone 8.1 and higher. So by using this library, you'll lose Windows Phone 8 compatibility.